# Returning Month and Year from Month Variable and Month-Year Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, flot.tooltip

I'm using jQuery Flot Chart and trying to configure my tool tips per my liking.

The chart I am creating is a stacked chart and has two overlaying charts with 12 points or markers on each line graph.

Each point indicates a month going back a year for each graph.

[image]

Probably easier to describe in picture. As noted in the legend light Blue is the previous 12 months, where as Yellow is the 12 months before that.

Anyways, I am initiating my own custom variable `yearrange` in the plot instance like so

```
$.plot($(".flot-line"), [{
            label: "Previous Year",
            yearrange: "Jul-2017 - Jun-2018",
            data: previousyear,
            color: "rgb(237,194,64)"
        }, {
            label: "Current Year",
            yearrange: "Jul-2018 - Jun-2019",
            data: currentyear,
            color: "rgb(175,216,248)"
        }]
```

And then using this tooltip function to overlay a tooltip on each point

```
$.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
    $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {                         
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                $("#tooltip").remove();

                var x = item.datapoint[0];
                var y = item.datapoint[1];                

                var currmonth = months[x-  1];
                var yearrange = item.series.yearrange;

                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                  "<strong> " + y + "</strong> (" + item.series.label + ")");
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }
    });
};
```

So--

I have two variables that I'm looking manipulate within this tooltip function to give me a desired output.

```
var currmonth = months[x-  1];
```

Which outputs the X-Axis label over which I am hovering (for example, `Nov`)

```
var yearrange = item.series.yearrange;
```

Which outputs from my custom variable insertion in flot (for example, `Jul-2017 - Jun-2018`)

Likewise, for example, on Current Year, `var currmonth = Jul` and `var yearrange = Jul-2018 - Jun-2019`

My question is how can I create a variable outputs the only Month & Year combination possible given the variables I'm working with.

Say my two variables are `Nov` and `Jul-2017 - Jun-2018`. The output I'm looking to get is the only November that is possible within those month ranges -- `November 2017`.

Likewise if I have something for the first year in the current month, variable `Jul` and variable `Jul-2018 - Jun-2019`-- the only July that will fit in this span would be an output of `July 2018`.

Comment: What if you have Nov and Jul-2017 - Jun-2019

Comment: That doesn't happen.  doing a `console.log(item)` inside my tooltip function the data brought back is only relevant to which line I am interacting with.  Therefore I will only ever get back the Month (as shown in the X axis), and either `"Jul-2017 - Jun-2018"` OR `"Jul-2018 - Jun-2019"`... never both or a combination of

Comment: I meant a range of 2 years

Comment: Well, right, that would be more complicated.  I can see your point if I wish to extend it further, but for all intents and purposes of this endeavor it's a 12-month span with only one month fit for the two variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with this - I updated it so you do not have to use moment.js to get the full monthname:

```js
const months = ",January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December".split(",")
const monthArr = months.map((month) => month.substring(0,3));
const pad = (num) => ("0"+num).slice(-2);

let getMonthYear = (curMonth,range) => {
  // Note: all string manipulation
  const curMonthStr = pad(monthArr.indexOf(curMonth));
  const [start,end] = range.split(" - ").map(
    d => d.replace(/(\w+)-(\d+)/,(m,a,b) => b+pad(monthArr.indexOf(a)))
  );
  const curYearMonthStart = start.slice(0,-2)+curMonthStr;
  const curYearMonthEnd   = end.slice(0,  -2)+curMonthStr;
  let curYearMonth        = curYearMonthStart;
  if (curYearMonth<start) curYearMonth = curYearMonthEnd; // which one do we take?
  return curYearMonth >= start && curYearMonth <=end ? months[monthArr.indexOf(curMonth)] + " " + curYearMonth.slice(0,-2) : "";
}

const range = "Jun-2018 - Jun-2019";

let curMonth = "Nov";
console.log(
  getMonthYear(curMonth,range)
)  
curMonth = "Jul";
console.log(
  getMonthYear(curMonth,range)
)
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Output works as I'd hoped. Only change I made was to take out the `"-"` in the return and used `moment.js` to convert it to the full month and year - `var getmonthyear = getMonthYear(currmonth, yearrange);`, and then `var monthyear = moment(getmonthyear, 'MMM Y').format('MMMM Y')`. Brings back full Months July 2017 to June 2019 depending on which point I'm hovering on the graph.  Many thanks.

Comment: Updated to NOT to have to use moment

Comment: Just tested - thank you! I was more or less using moment as quick-fix as I work though this, really appreciate the update.